# is Object.getPrototypeOf() same as Object.constructor.prototype in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, prototype-programming

Is there a difference between `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` and `obj.constructor.prototype`? Or are these two referencing the same thing?

Comment: You can upvote helpful questions and answers and also accept answers that solve your own questions. This helps organize SO and also is a small reward for those who helped you.

Comment: @missingno His questions so far are quite interesting though...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: He still deserves the "0%" boilerplate comment though :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**NO**

It returns the internal [`[[Prototype]]`](http://es5.github.com/#x8.6.2) value.

For example:

```
var o = Object.create(null);
Object.getPrototypeOf(o); // null
o.constructor.prototype; // error

var p = {};
var o = Object.create(p);
Object.getPrototypeOf(o); // p
o.constructor.prototype; // Object.prototype
```

`o.constructor.prototype` only works with objects created through `new ConstructorFunction` or where you have manually set the `Prototype.prototype.constructor === Prototype` relationship.

Answer (score 2):

**No**. In particular, the `constructor` property of an object is not always set to what you would consider "correct."

An example of where `getPrototypeOf` works but `.constructor.prototype` does not:

```
function F() { }
F.prototype = {
   foo: "bar"
};

var obj = new F();

assert.equal(obj.constructor.prototype, Object.prototype);
assert.equal(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj), F.prototype);
```

It also fails for typical prototypal inheritance scenarios:

```
// G prototypally inherits from F
function G() { }
G.prototype = Object.create(F.prototype);
// or: G.prototype = new F();

var obj2 = new G();

assert.equal(obj2.constructor.prototype, Object.prototype);
assert.equal(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj2), G.prototype);
assert.equal(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj2)), F.prototype);
```