# Why Object.getPrototypeOf(instance.constructor) is not equal to instance.constructor.prototype?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype

The title says its all, but here's the code:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}

const b = new B()


Object.getPrototypeOf(b.constructor) === b.constructor.prototype // false

Object.getPrototypeOf(b.constructor) === A // true
b.constructor.prototype === A // false. why?
```

I mean, the code above is counter-intuitive. Why is it made this way?

Comment: [Here is another set of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024879/is-object-getprototypeof-same-as-object-constructor-prototype-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf` does not simply access the `.prototype` property, it gets the internal link to the object that you inherit from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `__proto__` and `prototype` is not the same.

Let's say you have an object `obj`. Now, `obj.prototype` won't actually provide you with the prototype of `obj`, as you expect. To get the prototype of `obj` you have to do `obj.__proto__`. Run the following code and you'll have your answer. Also, Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959727/proto-vs-prototype-in-javascript) to know more about the differences between `__proto__` and `prototype`. :)

```js
class A {}
class B extends A {}

const b = new B()

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(b.constructor) === b.constructor.__proto__) // true
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(b.constructor) === A) // true
console.log(b.constructor.__proto__ === A) // true
```

Comment: Hmm.. the very first line of your answer instantly made me feel like an idiot, because it was so obvious... Thank you!

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf` *is* the same thing as `__proto__`.

Comment: "*To get the prototype of `obj` you have to do `obj.__proto__`*" - no, you have to do `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)`

Comment: @CertainPerformance No, it's not. `__proto__` is deprecated and doesn't even work on all objects.

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
b.constructor.prototype === A; // false
```

This is false because the prototype of b is the prototype of A not A itself. This may sound confusing at first so I left an example below:

```js
class A {}
class B extends A {}

const b = new B()


Object.getPrototypeOf(b.constructor) === b.constructor.prototype // false

Object.getPrototypeOf(b.constructor) === A // true
b.constructor.prototype === A // false. why?

console.dir(b.constructor.__proto__ === A); // true
```

In this example in the last statement:

```
console.dir(b.constructor.__proto__ === A); // true
```

The `__proto__` property of b actually refers to the same object, A.

You may find the following also interesting:

```js
class A {}

console.log(typeof A); // constructors are merely masked functions with added functionality

console.log(typeof A.__proto__);  // constructors inherit from the Function object

console.log(typeof A.__proto__.__proto__); // the Function object inherits from Object object
```